# Grails spring facebook load facebook credential from db

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security

I need help to make one change on  gralis spring security facebook plugin. Default configuration allows to set an appId and secret facebook credentials in Config.groovy.
 I need read it from my database because I need to login with many facebook apps from the same grails app.
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to make custom `facebookAuthUtils`. You can extend default `FacebookAuthUtils` class, and define it as a new Spring bean, that will replace default one.

I think all you need is to override `refreshAccessToken`, `getAccessToken` and `prepareRedirectUrl` methods. Maybe `getAuthCookie` also, if you're using cookie based auth. Current methods are using `applicationId` and `secret` from config file, but you can get them from db.